# WinForms Stopped Working Due to "Prblm Event Name CLR20r3

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

i created a program in c# and used SQL server 2008 as database and installshield for program .exe package

everything works fine i mean program can be installed normally and there is no error in database or in setup

but when i try to open program it gives the following error(program signature) which i took screenshot of error

i use dotNetBar.dll in my project and its included in setup folder

i changed path of installation and database folder but still the same error

Error screenshot part 1:

[image]

Error screenshot part 2:

[image]

please help.

Answer (score 1):

The error is the `FileNotFoundException`, your program is trying to open a file that's not there and you're not handling it in the code.

Have you copied everything?